# file_exists() in PHP and file path

Tags: php

I have a folder `uploads` in the root folder. There is another folder `A` in the root, and contains a PHP file. I have the following code in the PHP file:

```
$imgpath = '/uploads/' . $filename;
echo '<img src="' . $imgpath . '" />';
echo (file_exists($imgpath))?'true':'false';
```

It will show the image, so the file exists, but `file_exists` shows `false`.

If I change `'/uploads/'` to `'../uploads/'`, it will show the image and `file_exists` shows `true`. Even if there is no image, `file_exists` always shows `true`.

What is the problem?

*** Update ***

I tried `echo dirname(__FILE__);`. It shows `/....../A`, the `uploads` folder is located at `/....../uploads`. Moreover, I have another similar PHP file in folder `/....../m/A`. So I need some kind of universal path. How to get the root path, i.e., `/....../`?

I also tried `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, but the image cannot be shown, although the path is 100% correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid problems, it's easiest to use an absolute path with file_exists(). The system root `/` is not the same as your web root (e.g.,) `/var/www`

Try

```
# /var/www/A/script.php
$imgpath = '/uploads/' . $filename;

# check in /var/www/uploads/filename
if( file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..' . $imgpath) ) {
    echo '<img src="' . $imgpath . '" />';
}
```

EDIT for PHP >= 5.3

```
$path = "/uploads/${filename}";

if (file_exists(sprinf("%s/..%s", __DIR__, $path)) {
  echo "<img src=\"{$path}\">;
}
```

Comment: This works. But even if there is no such file, `file_exists` also show `true`. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Starting out with "/" means a relative path on the web, but on file systems that is referencing the folder "uploads" inside the root "/" directory.

Try `./uploads` notation or use `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Answer (score 2):

**The reason is that your absolute path in HTML is relative to your website root, but in PHP it is relative to the file-system root.**  They are not the same.

My website root is http://www.example.com/ but my site is developed on the file-system at `/var/www/`  So if I was in `/var/www/index.php` and used the path `/uploads/`, in html that would be http://www.example.com/uploads/ but for a file-system that would be `/uploads/`.  I'm not even in my website directory anymore!